# Wowza HTTP Live streaming San Jose vs Cupertino i.e Flash vs APPLE what exactly is the difference?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, live, wowza, http-streaming

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217#cupertinostreaming
The only difference i can make out is that flash http streaming uses an xml manifest and apple http streaming uses playlist warper.
I Am not sure if these are any different in concept.
What exactly is the purpose of having two different ways of implementing the same concept?.

I can see from the documentation the flash http streaming needs a flash based player built using OSMF. 
What player is required for apple http streaming.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever read the biology of Steve Jobs, you'll get the stories between Jobs and Adobe...

Flash HTTP streaming and Apple Live HTTP streaming are quite similar in nature, and for the same purpose. Apple just don't want to support Flash technology from Adobe.

BTW: Quicktime player on iOS devices is required for Apple Live HTTP streaming.

Answer (score 4):

The true answer for why support both is that flash only plays HDS (http dynamic streaming aka flash streaming aka sanjose streaming) and iOS / quicktime for OSX only support HLS (http live streaming).

A minor correction on the previous post is that Apple's Http Live Streaming was created first. Adobe went a different route because there is another key difference between the two. Apple's streaming is encapsulated in a mpeg2 transport protocol and Adobe's in an mpeg4 which they say is a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a difference, just who's team you chose to be on ;)

Simplest player solution for HLS is the HTML5  tags.

Answer (score 1):

To backup EdC's statements and more differences you can check out the following link:
[HLS vs. HDS – What Is the Difference and Why You Should Care](http://www.overdigital.com/2011/12/27/hls-vs-hds-what-is-the-difference-and-why-you-should-care/)